# PostgreSQL errors when feed in large data frame in R

Tags: r

I have been using the library(RPostgreSQL) package to do query for a large data frame, I noticed when the input data frame grows large, I kept have following errors.

I have assigned more than 200 GB of ram for the database instance, while the input data frame is just 2 GB. It is really puzzling how can I resolve this issue.

```
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  out of memory
DETAIL:  Cannot enlarge string buffer containing 0 bytes by 1159423767 more bytes.
)
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : Error sending variants to database
Calls: batchAnnotate ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

Comment: It seems to be related to the string buffer limits,

Comment: Can you add a e.g. `LIMIT 10` to the query and see if that breaks?